# How I can find elements between two elements in jquery?

Tags: jquery

1. I select `var checkboxes = $('.checkprice.checked');`
2. How I can find all checkboxes between first of found element and last?

And how I can do this:

3. Select all $('.checkprice') without .checked class, but between elements with checked class?

Comment: @Сергей, please only ask one question per post. If you have another question, feel free to post it as another question. Especially avoid editing a post to add additional requirements or other questions after you have received an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) supports negative indexes, so you only have to write:

```
var checkboxes = $(".checkprice.checked").slice(1, -1);
```

The pair of indexes passed in the code above means "from the second element in the set to the next-to-last one".

Comment: And then OP edited question making this valuable answer 'kind of' off topic... :(